# C++ initializing custom type in constructor

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
class SegmentTree {
public:
    unordered_map<int, int> tree;
    vector<int> nums;

    SegmentTree(vector<int> nums)  {
        this->nums = nums;
        build(0, nums.size() - 1, 1);
    }
};

class NumArray {
public:
    SegmentTree s;
    NumArray(vector<int> nums) {
        s = SegmentTree(nums);
    }
};
```

I am getting an error saying

> note: candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

Presumably SegmentTree is being initialized when I do `SegmentTree s`.

However, I want to initialize it only within the constructor of `NumArray`.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: `this->nums = nums;` - don't use the constructor body to *assign* values when you can use the constructors *initialization list* to *initialize* objects: `SegmentTree(vector<int> nums)  : nums(nums) {`. And you may consider naming your arguments different than your member variables (personally I always use a `m_` prefix for members) to reduce confusion and avoid problems with shadowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an *initaliser list*

```
NumArray(vector<int> nums) : s(nums) {
}
```

Assignment is not the same as initialisation. Your version tried to *default initialise* `s` and only then assign to it. But because your `SegmentTree` class has no default constructor this failed.